# File Size column with kb in sharepoint

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, gridview, filesize

I am using spgridview to display the items in a library based on library viewid. I am assigning the datasource as SPlist.items.getdatatable();. Here for file size column, I am getting the values in number. But i need to show in KB's.

How can i show the **filesize values with kb,mb as suffix without looping each column** in the datatable?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i know,

We can't do. The alternate is to do looping and apply validation for each row data.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this.... ?

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="HeaderText">
    <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" <%# Convert.ToString(Eval("ColumnName")/1024) + " KB" %> ></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: You can calculate in the same way, if you want in MB then can divide it Convert.ToString(Eval("ColumnName")/1024*1024)